# Why does my Vue/Vite/Typescript application require me to separate "import" and "import type" by default?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs3, vite

I've scaffolded a front-end application using [create-vue](https://github.com/vuejs/create-vue). It includes TypeScript.

The following throws an error:

```
import axios, { AxiosInstance, AxiosResponse } from "axios"
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/axios.js?v=a7006e8b' does not provide an export named 'AxiosInstance'

Whereas the following works:

```
import axios from "axios"
import type { AxiosInstance, AxiosResponse } from "axios"
```

This is my first time using `create-vue`, but in other projects in the past I have never had to separate my type imports.

The documentation for [`verbatimModuleSyntax`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#verbatimModuleSyntax) states:

> By default, TypeScript does something called *import elision*. TypeScript detects that you’re only using an import for types and drops the import entirely.

To be safe, I tried setting `"verbatimModuleSyntax": "false"` to my `tsconfig.json`, but this did not fix the issue. It's also flagged in VSCode with the following error:

> Do not transform or elide any imports or exports not marked as type-only, ensuring they are written in the output file's format based on the 'module' setting.

How can I get the failing line (importing both classes and types/interfaces in one line) to work as it always has for me in the past?

**EDIT:** Note that I'm using axios only as an example. This happens with any type, regardless of whether it's a node module or an interface I've written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"verbatimModuleSyntax": "false"` doesn't work, but `"verbatimModuleSyntax": false` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
import axios, { type AxiosInstance, type AxiosResponse } from "axios"
```

The difference of "type" imports is they get stripped
If they wouldn't get stripped, you would try to import an actual `AxiosInstance` variable from `axios`, resulting in a runtime error *if so-named variable was not exported from there*.
`verbatimModuleSyntax` disables the stripping of unused non-"type" imports, causing the error

```
import { a } from './a'
import { type b } from './b'
import type { c } from './c'
import { d, /* type */ e, type f } from './d'
import { /* unused */u, /* type */ w, type y } from './u'
a<b, c, e, d, f, w>(d)


// JS without verbatimModuleSyntax
// import { a } from './a';
// import { d } from './d';
// a(d);

// JS with verbatimModuleSyntax
// import { a } from './a';
// import {} from './b';
// import { d, e } from './d';
// import { u, w } from './u';
// a(d);
```

Comment: Thank you. Like I mentioned though, I have never had to use a `type` import at all. Is it a typescript version thing? I'm trying to figure out why all my other projects work fine but this one does not. I've always imported interfaces and classes this way.

Comment: because with `verbatimModuleSyntax` they stopped being trimmed @Santi

Comment: Then how do I turn it off...?

Comment: @Santi you go to tsconfig.json and turn it off

Comment: As I said in the original post, I did that, and it didn't work

Comment: @Santi Then I'd recommend that one  ESLint autofix that autoplaces `type` in imports for you, see https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/consistent-type-imports/